# Using roll your own authentication with the rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How do you implement authentication with the [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) when you are not using devise e.g. you have rolled your own authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` include a `config.authenticate_with` block and place your authentication logic there. It should raise an exception if the user is not authorised to use rails_admin.  Here is a simple example:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    raise 'You must be admin' unless signed_in? && current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

If you want to follow the `rails_admin` instructions for the `cancancan` gem then also add the following config line:

```
config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```