# Roll your own authentication with the rails_admin gem stops working with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966781/1299362) shows how to authenticate the `rails_admin gem` when you have a roll your own authentication. The method follows this [pattern](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization). However, this solution no longer works with `rails 5`. Instead, when trying to access an admin view, the following exception is triggered in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
undefined method `signed_in?' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController:0x007fbe38628ab0>
```

How do you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual view helpers, like `signed_in?` or `current_user` are no longer accessible in the initializer, so the solution that I came up with was:

```
config.authenticate_with do
    current_user =  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    raise 'You must be admin' unless current_user.try(:admin?)
  end
```